# Changing a Select tag with Javascript in base of other choices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not sure if what I what to do is feasible, but I will give it a try to explain it and maybe we could find something close to it.

I have many select tags in an HTML form (>10) with exactly the same options. The number of options is also high (>20).

Here is an example

```
<select>
<option>A1</option>
<option>A2</option>
<option>A3</option>
<option>A4</option>
<option>B1</option>
<option>B2</option>
<option>B3</option>
......
</select>
```

I want to create a few "If this then that" cases.

- The simpler one is "If a user choose one option", then this option will be removed from all the other select tags.
- The other one is if someone choose 2 options of the same "team" (for example [A1,A2,A3]) in two different select tags, then the third option will also be removed from the others.

I believe that I could do it with many, many, many if statements, but I was thinking for something more simple.

For example, I could create 4-5 lists with the "teams" and change the cases as:

- If the choice in the list, then remove it from all the other selections
- If 2 or 3 choices (based in the team), then remove all the others from that team on the other selections.

If you think that there is also another way to do it except of dropdown menus, I could change it if it is a better option.

**Edit: If anyone want to add a bounty (50 points) to attract more answers, feel free to do it. I don't have the amount of reputation to do it.**

Comment: doesn't the first condition contradict the second? If you remove a `team`, then the second condition will never occur (selecting two of the same team)?

Comment: Remove the option of the team. For example if I choose the A1, then A2, A3 and A4 will be the only available. And if I choose 2 of the A team, then all the team will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with jquery.

html

```
<select>
    <option class="A" value="A1">A1</option>
    <option class="A" value="A2">A2</option>
    <option class="A" value="A3">A3</option>
    <option class="A" value="A4">A4</option>
    <option class="B" value="B1">B1</option>
    <option class="B" value="B2">B2</option>
    <option class="B" value="B3">B3</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option class="A" value="A1">A1</option>
    <option class="A" value="A2">A2</option>
    <option class="A" value="A3">A3</option>
    <option class="A" value="A4">A4</option>
    <option class="B" value="B1">B1</option>
    <option class="B" value="B2">B2</option>
    <option class="B" value="B3">B3</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option class="A" value="A1">A1</option>
    <option class="A" value="A2">A2</option>
    <option class="A" value="A3">A3</option>
    <option class="A" value="A4">A4</option>
    <option class="B" value="B1">B1</option>
    <option class="B" value="B2">B2</option>
    <option class="B" value="B3">B3</option>
</select>
```

javascript

```
var teams_counter = {};
var prev_value, prev_team;

$("select").each(function(i,sel){
    sel.selectedIndex = -1;
    $(sel).children().each(function(j,opt){
        teams_counter[opt.className] = 0;
    });
});

$("select").focus(function(evt){
    prev_value = evt.target.value;
    var opt = evt.target.selectedOptions[0];
    prev_team = opt ? opt.className : undefined;
});

$("select").change(function(evt){
    var sel_team = evt.target.selectedOptions[0].className;
    teams_counter[sel_team] += 1;
    if(teams_counter[sel_team] >= 2){
        //$("." + sel_team).hide(); // this is not good.
        $("select").filter(function(){
            return !this.selectedOptions[0] || this.selectedOptions[0].className != sel_team;
        }).find("." + sel_team).hide();
    };
    if(prev_team){
        teams_counter[prev_team] -= 1;
        if(teams_counter[prev_team] < 2){
            $("." + prev_team).show();
        }
    }
    $("option[value='" + evt.target.value + "']").hide();
    $("option[value='" + prev_value + "']").show();
});
```

Comment: Something doesn't work properly on jsfiddle. When I choose one option, the it is still active on the other dropdowns.

Comment: Sorry, I only observed my code working in Chrome. "selectedOptions" seems to be not available in firefox or ie. I will fix lator.